# Serilog for C#, 3 minutes delay of writing to file

Tags: serilog

I got suggested to use Serilog for my server application, and it is easier than writing my own logger

However, when logging a line in Serilog, it takes around 3 minutes for the text to reach the file.
Google etc cannot tell me why.

My code:

```
  //Add Serilog
            string logFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/new_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log");
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(
                    path: logFileName,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: 7,
                    shared: true,
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                    fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456)
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("Starting Serilog #1");
```

And simply:

```
        [Route("ping")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Ping()
        {
            // this will be in the log file 3 minutes after the ping
            Log.Information("Pinged"); 

            return Ok("Pong");
        }
```

What can cause Serilog to have this delay?

Answer (score 0):

This happens for performance reasons, as writing to disk all the time would be very slow (order of milliseconds). The default approach is to write logs to the operating system page cache, and the OS takes care of writing to disk later, which in your case seems to take around 3 minutes on your server.

If you need to force a "flush to disk" more frequently, you can use the `flushToDiskInterval` setting when configuring your sink:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(
        //...
        flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .CreateLogger();
```

The example above should force logs being written to disk every `5` seconds, which you can adapt to a different number where the performance hit would be acceptable.